# When is the limit of a sum equal to the sum of limits?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I was trying to solve a problem and got stuck at the following step:

Suppose ${n \to \infty}$ .

$$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^3}{n^3} = 1$$

Let us rewrite $n^3=n \cdot n^2$ as $n^2 + n^2 + n^2 + n^2 \dots +n^2$,$\space$ n times.

Now we have

$$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^3}{n^3} = \frac {n^2 + n^2 + n^2 + n^2 + n^2 \dots +n^2}{n^3} $$

As far as I understand, we can always rewrite the limit of a sum as the sum of limits ...

$$\dots = \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{n^2}{n^3} + \frac{n^2}{n^3} + \dots + \frac{n^2}{n^3}\right)$$

...but we can only let ${n \to \infty}$ and calculate the limit if all of the individual limits are of defined form (*is this correct?*). That would be the case here, so we have:

$= \dots \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n} + \dots + \frac{1}{n}\right) =$[ *letting* ${n \to \infty}]$ $= 0 + 0 + \dots + 0 = 0$

and the results we get are not the same.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Keep in mind that the number of summands in *not fixed*.

Comment: "*We can always rewrite the limit of the sum as the sum of the limits*."  As you just found, that is not true.  One can not always change nested limits around.  For additional counterexample, consider $1 = \lim\limits_{x\to 0} \lim\limits_{y\to 0} x^y \neq \lim\limits_{y\to 0} \lim\limits_{x\to 0} x^y = 0$.  You may be interested in reading about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini's_theorem

Comment: You cannot replace only a part of the expression with its limit, that's all. You have more and more terms, each getting smaller and smaller. Informally speaking, you do not have $n$ terms equal to $0$ but, so to say, an infinity of $0$s.

Comment: One way to look at it this way is to write $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n^3}{n^3}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac1n \sum_{k=1}^n(1)$, which is the Riemann sum for $1$ over an interval of unit length.  Of course, the value of the integral is $1$.

Comment: @JMoravitz This confuses me, because I thought that one can, in the case of $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} f(x) $, *always* swap $lim$ and $f(x)$, under the condition that $f(x)$ is a continuous function.
Thank you for the suggestion for further reading!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because the number of terms goes up exactly as the size of each term goes down.

Specifically $$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \Big(\underbrace{\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n} + \dots + \frac{1}{n}}_{n\text{ times}}\Big) = \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac 1n$$

Does that help?

Comment: @Battani That proposed edit was incorrect.  I realize it might look weird to not have any $i$'s in the summand but it really *is* supposed to be $\sum\limits_i \frac 1n = \frac 1n\sum\limits_i 1 = \frac 1n(n) = 1$.

Comment: If we pull out the $\frac{1}{n}$ expression in front of the sum, we are left $\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}\frac1n \sum_{k=1}^n1$ as mentioned in one of the comments above. The limit is 1, because I have an infinite sum of terms that are all slightly bigger than 0. Did I understand this correctly?

Comment: Yep.$\ \ \ \ \ $

Comment: Is there a general rule for rewriting the limit of a sum as the sum of limits?

Comment: Assuming you have a finite sum, you can do so if [each of the limits in the expression converges](http://www.oxfordmathcenter.com/drupal7/node/94).  It gets a little more complicated though with *infinite* sums.

Answer (score 8):

The problem you have described is common and there are three possible scenarios to cover:

1. **Number of terms is finite and independent of $n$**: The limit of a sum is equal to sum of limits of terms provided each term has a limit.
2. **Number of terms is infinite**: Some sort of uniform convergence of the infinite series is required and under suitable conditions the limit of a sum is equal to the sum of limits of terms.
3. **Number of terms is dependent on $n$**: This is the case which applies to the question at hand. The problem is difficult compared to previous two cases and a partial solution is provided by [Monotone Convergence Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem#Theorem_2). Sadly the theorem does not apply to your specific example. But it famously applies to the binomial expansion of $(1+n^{-1})^n$ and gives the result $$e=1+1+\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{3!}+\dots$$