# Confusion in this limits problem

Tags: calculus, limits, summation

> Evaluate $$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \frac{1^2 + 2^2 +...+n^2}{n^3}$$

This is the original method to solve this is:

*Taking summation of the square numbers $1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 +...+n^2 = \frac{1}{6}n(n+1)(2n+1)$*
$$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \frac{1^2 + 2^2 +...+n^2}{n^3} = \frac{\frac{1}{6}n(n+1)(2n+1)}{n^3}$$
$$=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{(n+1)(2n+1)}{6n^2} = \lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{6}(1+\frac{1}{n})(2+\frac{1}{n})$$
$$=\frac{2}{6} = \frac{1}{3}$$

But when looking at the limit in a different angle I get a different answer,

$$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \frac{1^2 + 2^2 +...+n^2}{n^3} = \lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \frac{1^2}{n^3}+\frac{2^2}{n^3}+...+\frac{1}{n}$$
$$=0+0+...+0 = 0$$

*Both the method seem right to me, but why I am getting different answers? What have I done wrong?* Please Explain. Thank you!

Comment: You cannot evaluate the limit like this, because you have $n$-terms with $n\to \infty$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde But why? If $n\to \infty$, then it is still going to be $0+0+....=0$ infinitely

Comment: Your claim in the 2nd part is not true, as for any $\epsilon > 0$ you can not find any $K\in\mathbb N$ for which $|\frac{1^2+2^2+\dots +n^2}{n^3}|<\epsilon$ for all $n>\ge K$

Comment: @rash Certainly not. Take $n$-times $\frac{1}{n}$ as a sum. Each term goes to $0$, but the sum is always $1$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Again how is it possible? Sorry, I do not get u well...

Comment: Because, as you showed in your first answer, when you add an infinite number of terms, each of which tends to zero, the sum can be nonzero. An easy example of this is n terms each being 1/n. The sum is 1 while each term tends to zero.

Comment: @rash: What is important is that you have $n$ terms. That is, try to look at it this way: $c_n=a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n$. It doesn't make sense to say $$\lim_{n\to\infty}c_n=\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}a_1\right)+\cdots\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\right)$$ since as $n$ becomes large, $c_n$ includes more and more terms whereas on the right, you're acting as though the number of terms is fixed.

Comment: @rash Again how is this possible that you don't see that $\frac{1}{n}+\cdots +\frac{1}{n}=1$ for $n$ summands?

Comment: Arithmetic of limits works when the number of sequences in the sum is finite. But you can't use it for a number of sequences that is dependent on $n$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1598719/when-is-the-limit-of-a-sum-equal-to-the-sum-of-limits) question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting the limit into an integral is one right way to evaluate it.

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{1^2+2^2+\cdots+n^2}{n^3}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\dfrac{k}{n}\right)^2=\int_{0}^{1}x^2\mathrm dx$$

Comment: Change "_the_ right way" to "_one_ right way" and I agree. See OP's question for "_another_ way"...

Comment: Edit made @StackTD